# Sql alter column value without deleting the old one

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there some way of on a certain table column add an value to the column but keeping the old value?

I have this:

```
 id | dateB/dateE  |
 1  | 2018-07-05   | 
 2  | 2018-07-05   |
```

I want after an `update`:

```
 id | dateB/dateE             |
 1  | 2018-07-05/ 2018-07-06  | 
 2  | 2018-07-05/ 2018-07-06  |
```

Comment: There is no reason why you should want to store 2 dates in one column here. That is worthless because you can't query the column directly for even simple date operations. Remember - do not store dates as strings ever in database. It is advisable to have two separate date columns in your case.

Comment: This approach is not scaleable. What would the data look like after 100 updates? Better to use a separate child table.

Comment: @Bohemian there will be always 2 dates, the begin date and the end date. So only one update will be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
update my_table set col2 = col2 || '/ 2018-07-06';
```

Answer (score 2):

A better solution:

```
alter table t add column dateB date;
alter table t add column dateE date;

update t
    set dateB = col2,
        dateE = date '2018-07-06';

alter table t drop column col2;
```

That is, store values using the correct types.